# Font sizes in px in modern browsers (is it good, what about 120 dpi?)

Tags: css, xhtml

I used to use the 'font-sizes in ems' approach (mostly for IE users)  and some CSS hacks to have the same font size on systems where screen is set to 120dpi. I know that forcing the same font size in 120 dpi is not good in usability terms, but this is the way I should get it done.

I'm curious is it good to switch to pixels instead of ems, as far as I see all my target browsers (IE7,8; FF 3.6, Chrome 5, Opera 10.6, Safari Win) support full page zoom.

I have the following restrictions:

- No IE6 support
- Font size should be the same in 96dpi and 120dpi (I usually have many graphics that requires that text should be in some particular size).

Should I switch?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about displays with 125 DPI? Or 150? I've got a notebook and phone with both. Do you know how difficult is to read 8px text at 150 DPI?

Comment: liori, I believe artvolk is referring to Windows's "custom text size (DPI)" setting. Some users, particularly those with poor vision, prefer to boost the "dpi" of their system's font and icon sizes rather than lowering their resolution. On Win7, for example, go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display, and select "Set custom text size (DPI)" on the left.

Comment: Oh, and as for the original question: If a user has a large default font size, they probably have a reason for it. Don't circumvent them by forcing a small font size. Also, it's generally not a good idea design in a manner that's dependent on a very specific font size and text flow--even if you manage a consistent font size, it still won't be perfect everywhere, since font rendering and availability varies wildly across platforms and browsers.

Comment: Yes, you all are right that it is not good to force font to be the same, but this is a common requirement for projects I'm working on and I can't change this at least for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally recommend to stick w/ em- or %-based font-sizes to avoid headaches related w/ the pixel based approaches. However, you might want to use px for the base font size and adjust it w/ [CSS3 media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to your needs (particularly querying for the [resolution](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#resolution) should help you).

The downside of this method is that, as so often, IE 7 and 8 will need yet another hack as IE is the only browser in your list currently not supporting media queries. hth & good luck!

Comment: Currently I use 'ems' + some fixes for 120 dpi on Windows (special hacks for IE and media queries for all other browsers).

If I use pixels, will the text be the same in 120dpi without hacks?

What are headaches you mentioned?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about "the same"? A pixel's size (in mm or inch or the like)  depends on the resolution and the size of a screen.

Comment: The same I mean in px, because the graphics remain the same size in px.